# MS Access: Using Text within Unbound Text Box as Control to Refresh different Forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am sure that someone has a different way to do this, so please set me on the right path if this isn't the best method.

In MS Access I have different user types that all have different dashboards.  All of these users can press a button on their dashboard to get a common overlay to enter a new record.  Upon hitting save on the overlay, I need to refresh the subform on the dashboard with the new records.  I have used vba that looks for open forms and then refreshes based on the form that is open, but I don't like this method because each time I create a new user type I have to remember to go back and update the code to look for this new dashboard.  More recently I tried updating an unbound textbox on the overlay with the name of the form/subfrm that needs to be update, but I can't seem to get that to run correctly.

Here is my VBA that is run upon trying to save the record and update the correct form. (Note me.txtFrmRefresh is my unbound textbox)

```
Dim ctlFrmRefresh As Control

Set ctlFrmRefresh = me.txtFrmRefresh

ctlFrmRefresh.Form.Recordset.Requery
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmClaimNew", acSaveNo
```

When I run this, get the following error "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property form/report.

I know that the text in the unbound textbox is correct because I can change "me.txtFrmRefresh" to the form name and it works correctly.

Comment: No.  One form is an overlay/popup and the other form is in the background.  Upon save an close I need to refresh a variable form in the background.  txtFrmRefresh is on the overlay/popup.

Comment: The unbound textbox (me.txtFrmRefresh) value is "Forms!frmAdmnDshbd.navAdmnDshbd.Form!subfrmGnrlNavClaims", so it is pointing to a form that has a navigation panel that has a subform.

Comment: @HansUp - thanks for that!  I will give it a try here in a sec.

Comment: Opposite, "Forms!frmAdmnDshbd.navAdmnDshbd.Form" is the variable.  Goes to "Forms!frmEngrDshbd.navEngrDshbd.Form" for an engineers dashboard.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I will give it a try.

Comment: So each user type has a main form that is a 'dashboard' and this dashboard has a subform that needs to be refreshed? Is this code in the dashboard module? How different are these dashboard forms? I have never used `Recordset.Requery`. Maybe this would accommodate: `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"`.

Comment: I have found Recordset.Requery to be EXTREMLY handy.  It maintains the position of the selected record when the requery happens.  Prevents it from jumping back to the top of the page.  I will look into your suggestion. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to requery a form

To requery a Form:

Forms!FormName!Requery
Forms(“FormNam”).Requery
Forms!FormName!SubformControl!Form!Tequery (if it’s a subform)

Comment: really appreciate the feedback.  The form that I need refreshed changes depending on the user.  I would rather not write a long if statement that loops through the user types and finds the correct form to refresh in VBA but rather find a way to code it so that I don't need to change things if user profiles are added or change.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get Eval to work, but it kept throwing an Object Required error.  Ended up having to go back to my old way here I have an IF statement look for the dashboard that is open and then execute the refresh based off of that.

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms(strFrmAdmnRefresh).IsLoaded Then
Set ctlFrmAdmnRefresh = Forms!frmAdmnDshbd.navAdmnDshbd.Form!subfrmAdmnNavClaims
ctlFrmAdmnRefresh.Form.Recordset.Requery
```